# File Object has a Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, pointers, exception, null, program-entry-point

I am having trouble in this lines, specifically the File array failuSarasas. It is returning null.

```
//obj.generateIndexes(failuSarasas, 2);
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> indTwoList = obj.generateIndexes(failuSarasas, 2);
```

within

---

```
public class mainas
{
      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
        {
            mainas obj = new mainas();
            File[] failuSarasas = obj.getFileList();

            //obj.generateIndexes(failuSarasas, 2);
            HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> indTwoList = obj.generateIndexes(failuSarasas, 2);
            obj.printHashMap(indTwoList);
            //obj.generateIndexMatrix(indTwoList, failuSarasas);

            // More code...
        }

    public File[] getFileList()
    {
        File folder = new File(
                " C:\\Users\\Dell Pc\\Desktop\\inform\\Informacijos modeliavimas\\Informacijos modeliavimas\\ld2\\pages");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        return listOfFiles;
    }

    // More code...
}
```

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/5221149)

Comment: Can you give specifics on what error or unexpected result you're running into, and the expected output?

Comment: Please learn [how to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at modeliavimas2.mainas.generateIndexes(mainas.java:46)
 at modeliavimas2.mainas.main(mainas.java:15)

Comment: sooo sorry i am new in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `failuSarasas` object is null, because this bit of code seems to be returning null:

`public File[] getFileList()
    {
        File folder = new File(
                " C:\\Users\\Dell Pc\\Desktop\\inform\\Informacijos modeliavimas\\Informacijos modeliavimas\\ld2\\pages");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        return listOfFiles;
    }`

You may want to check that the files exist before you even do anything with your new `File` object. The `File` class has an `exist()` method that you can use to do just that. Good luck!

**EDIT:**
Per Oracle docs...

> public File[] listFiles()
>
> Returns an array of abstract pathnames denoting the files in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname.
>
> If this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, then this method returns null. Otherwise an array of File objects is returned, one for each file or directory in the directory...

See that third paragraph? That's why I suspect that the path you're providing does not exist, which is why I'm saying do a check first, via `File#exists()` method.

Here's the link to the File docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()

P.S. Unless you're required to use `File`, I suggest you use `Files` and those items in that package (`java.nio.file`).

Comment: so why Failu sarasas is null? if he had to take with method getFileList?

Comment: Please read my edited answer. This should answer your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for the excellent explanation. The trouble was that when setting the directory, the letter C was written like a capital letter! ; D " C:\\Users\\Dell Pc\\Desktop\\inform\\Informacijos modeliavimas\\Informacijos modeliavimas\\ld2\\pages")"